# How to call lua functions with C thread multiple times

Tags: c, multithreading, lua

The following code crashes each time at a different part and for a different reason. Tried everything. I want to be able to call "sleep" from lua script and to call lua functions multiple times without my C program having to wait for lua finishes. In my example, I "simulate" 500 mouse clicks at position `x = 100` and `y = 200` at the speed of 1 click per millisecond.

```c
#include <windows.h>
#include <lua.hpp>

struct MouseClick{
    lua_State *L;
    int x, y;
};

int sleep(lua_State *L)
{
    Sleep(lua_tointeger(L, 1));
    return 0;
}

void onClicK(lua_State *L, int x, int y)
{
    lua_getglobal(L, "onClick");

    lua_newtable(L);
    lua_pushinteger(L, x); lua_setfield(L, -2, "x");
    lua_pushinteger(L, y); lua_setfield(L, -2, "y");

    lua_pcall(L, 1, 0, 0);
}

void callThread(LPVOID arg)
{
    MouseClick *m = (MouseClick*) arg;
    onClicK(m->L, m->x, m->y);
}

int main()
{
    lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
    if (luaL_loadfile(L, "test.lua"))
    {
        printf("Script not loaded.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    luaL_openlibs(L);
    lua_register(L, "sleep", sleep);
    luaL_dofile(L, "test.lua");

    for(int i = 0; i < 500; i++, Sleep(1))
    {
        MouseClick m = {lua_newthread(L), 100, 200};
        CreateThread(0, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) callThread, &m, 0, 0);
    }

    getchar();
}
```

Lua side:

```lua
function onClick(c)
  print(c.x, c.y)
  sleep(3000)
end
```

Comment: Lua is not multithread-friendly.  `lua_newthread(L)` creates new execution stack inside the same global Lua state.  WinAPI function `CreateThread` creates new OS threads, but global Lua state is not thread-safe (it is not allowed to be used from multiple OS threads simultaneously), that's why you are getting unpredictable errors.  You should create separate global Lua state with `luaL_newstate()` for each OS thread, but in this case your threads will not have common objects, they will be absolutely separated and will not see each other.  Some external libraries exist to solve this problem.

Comment: Thanks, Egor. I thought this could be the problem. Do you know some library I can use for my purpose?

Comment: [Lua Multitasking](http://lua-users.org/wiki/MultiTasking)